# Accessing ViewController from it's parent class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a lot of viewControllers that have a common parent class

```
@interface X_ViewController : ParentViewController 
{
}
```

in `ParentViewController` I want to run some code that does the actual things on the ViewController itself
Specifically `UIActionSheet`.
Inside `ParentViewController`, `self.view` is the wrong thing to do.
How can I still access the "child" (which is actually my own object's) view?

Comment: what is it that you want to do ? maybe your creating the wrong problem.

Comment: Parent shouldn't know nothing about his children. Can you paste here the code: the parent and child function you want to call and the place where you call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe this is not possible.
You can access `childViewController`in different cases, but not this one.

Your approach, IMO, is wrong.
You should make some public methods in your `parentVC` and let its child calls them. Not the other way around.

Comment: and pass self as an argument?

Comment: I hoped that self.view is something I can use in the base class code

Comment: what you're doing is making your `childVC` inherits from `parentVC`. It's not guarantee that your `parent and child VC` exist at the same time. You've to make sure that they exist and when they do exist, you can treat them as same level viewcontroller (I guess you're not using presentViewController, right ?). After that, depend on your approach, you could access any VC you want

Comment: self.view only refers to the parent's view.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `self` to `X_ViewController`.

```
if ([self isKindOfClass:[X_ViewController class]]) {
    [((X_ViewController *)self) doSomething];
}
```

But I would discourage this. You use subclasses so that you get inheritance, not the other way round (pension?).

Comment: indeed. I hoped that self.view is something I can use in the base class code

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is no. `self.view` is an instance of `UIView`, not `UIViewController`, which means it's a view instead of a controller as in MVC pattern. If you find yourself in this situation, something is probably wrong with your design. The better approach would be fixing it, instead of looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

import your child VC in your parent.(very unethical i might say)

create reference of your child VC in your parent and then call the method u want to execute